# Multiplication operator is injective if and only if its range is dense

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

I was working on couple of questions regarding multiplication operators and I couldn't figure out how to proceed for this one.

Let $f \in L^{\infty} ([a,b])$ be continuous and consider the multiplication operator $M_f$ defined as $M_f : L^{2} ([a,b]) \to L^{2} ([a,b])$.

$M_f(h) = fh$ for $h \in L^2 ([a,b])$.   I want to show that $M_f$ is injective if and only if $R(M_f)$ is dense in $L^2([a,b])$.

We know that $M_f$ is injective if and only if $f \neq 0$ a.e. in $[a,b]$. I have managed to show this.

I believe showing that  $f \neq 0$ a.e. in $[a,b]$ if and only if $R(M_f)$ is dense in $L^2([a,b])$ is a good way to approach this problem but I couldn't figure out how to proceed from here. I would appreciate any help!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

in the comments i say that i will delete my answer but i can't because it's accepted..

Comment: I don't follow this answer. First, the question regards $L^{\infty}$ functions and not continuous ones. But most importantly, there are plenty continuous functions that satisfy "$f \neq 0$ a.e." and not "$f \neq 0$ everywhere". Am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: @Kore-N the question regards continuous functions

Comment: Yes, you are right, sorry. Still, the function $f(x)=x$ satisfies $f(x)\neq 0$ for almost all $x \in [-1,1]$. But $f(0) = 0$.

Comment: @Kore-N Oh, right. Anyway, we can still define $g=1/f$ almost everywhere, this is continuous almost everywhere and $gf=1$ almost everywhere. The rest of the proof goes through verbatim.

Comment: I still disagree a bit. In the lemma you quote, I think with invertible is meant heaving a *bounded* inverse. Since $1/f$ blows up near zero, the "inverse" you construct is not really a bounded operator on $L^2$. I think this is the subtle difference between being in the resolvent set or being in the continuous spectrum of an operator. In this case $0$ lies in the continuous spectrum of $M_f$ as soon as $f$ has a zero.

Comment: @Kore-N You are right. There are problems in my approach, I will delete it.

Answer (score 0):

Three observations:

1.$M^*_f=M_{\overline{f}}$. Here $*$ means conjugation of operator, $\overline{f}$ means conjugation of function $f$.

2.$\textrm{Ran}^{\perp}M=\textrm{Ker}M^*$

3.A subspace of a Hilbert space is dense if and only if it’s orthogonal complement is zero.
Together with above, we see $$\textrm{Ran}^{\perp}M_f=\text{Ker}M_{\overline{f}}.$$
So $\textrm{Ran}M_f$ is dense if and only if $\textrm{Ker}M_{\overline{f}}=0$, this is equivalent to $\overline{f}\neq 0$ a.e. by your attempt.

Answer (score 0):

I'll drop the continuity assumption.

Suppose $M_{f}$ is injective and let if possible the measure $\mu\{f=0\}\neq 0$

Then we have that $M_{f}(\mathbf{1}_{\{f=0\}})=0$ a.e. but $\mathbf{1}_{\{f=0\}}$ is not $0$ a.e. which contradicts injectivity.

Thus we have $\mu\{f=0\}=0$ .

Now consider $g\in Range(T)^{\perp}$ . So $\int_{[a,b]}M_{f}(h)g\,d\mu=\int_{[a,b]}fhg\,d\mu=0$ for all $h\in L^{2}[a,b]$

This means that $\langle h,fg\rangle=0$ for all $h\in L^{2}[a,b]$ which means that $fg=0$ a.e.

But as $\mu\{f=0\}=0$, you have that $g=0$ a.e.

Thus $Range(T)^{\perp}=\{0\}$ which proves that $\overline{Range(T)}=L^{2}[a,b]$.

Conversely if $\overline{Range(T)}=L^{2}[a,b]$ then again we have that $\mu\{f=0\}=0$ as otherwise $\mathbf{1}_{f=0}$ is in $Range(T)^{\perp}$ and $\mathbf{1}_{\{f=0\}}\neq 0$.

And this also shows that $M_{f}(h)=0$ implies $h=0$ a.e. which implies injectivity.

So both conditions are equivalent and they are also equivalent to $\mu\{f=0\}=0$.